# Using multiple InputReaders on a single input stream

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, inputstream, streamreader

I am trying to read multiple xml documents from a single input stream with JAXB. Since JAXB itself doesn't support this, I created my own XmlReader. However, that forces me to use multiple XMLEventReaders on this single input stream (after each other, not in parallel).

But that doesn't seem to work. The first XML document is read correctly. But the second is not. Depending on the XML, sometimes it just stops after the first XML document, sometimes it only returns arbitrary tags from the middle of the XML (don't know how this happens).

This is the code I use to read the XML:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class XmlReader {

  private final XMLInputFactory infactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  private final InputStream inStream;

  private String lastInvalidInput= null;

  public XmlReader(final InputStream inStream){
    this.inStream= inStream;
  }


  public String readXml() throws XMLStreamException{
    final XMLEventReader eventReader= infactory.createXMLEventReader(inStream);

    final StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    final Stack<String> openTags= new Stack<String>();
    boolean endOfXml= false;
    while (eventReader.hasNext() && !endOfXml){
      try{
        final XMLEvent nextEvent= eventReader.nextEvent();
        sb.append(nextEvent.toString());
        if (nextEvent.isStartElement()){
          openTags.add(nextEvent.toString());
        }else if (nextEvent.isEndElement()){
          openTags.pop();
          if (openTags.isEmpty()){
            endOfXml= true;
          }
        }
      }catch(XMLStreamException e){
        //FIXME: There must be cleaner way to recognize the end of the stream.
        if (e.getMessage().endsWith("ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]\nMessage: Premature end of file.")){
          if (openTags.isEmpty()){
            return null;
          }else{
            lastInvalidInput= sb.toString();
            throw new XMLStreamException("Unfinished XML stream", e);
          }
        }else{
          lastInvalidInput= sb.toString();
          throw e;
        }                                                                                                                                       
      }
    }

    eventReader.close();
    return sb.toString();
  }


  public String getLastInvalidInput() {
    return lastInvalidInput;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final File f= new File("/tmp/test.xml");
    final XmlReader r= new XmlReader(new FileInputStream(f));

    String xml;
    while((xml= r.readXml()) != null){
      System.out.println("------------");
      System.out.println(xml);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is an example XML file to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="latin3"?>
<myxml>
  <eins>
    <zwei>
      <drei>
      </drei>
    </zwei>
  </eins>
  <vier>
    <fuenf>
    </fuenf>
  </vier>
</myxml>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="latin1"?>
<yourxml>
  <one>
    <two>
      <three />
    </two>
  </one>
  <four>
    <five>
    </five>
  </four>
</yourxml>
```

Why this strange behaviour? I thought after closing the first XMLEventReader (which, according to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#close%28%29), doesn't close the input stream) the next can be used to read from the stream. Isn't this the case?

Is there some better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this old [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711766/multiple-xml-files-in-one-stream) this may help you
Usage

```
MultiXMLDocReader xmlReader = new MultiXMLDocReader(new InputStreamReader(anyInputStream));
ObjectA a = (ResponseHeader) u.unmarshal(xmlReader);
ObjectB b = (SubmissionProgress) u2.unmarshal(xmlReader);
```